# List Comprehension: Elegantly strip and remove empty elements in list

Tags: python, scrapy, list-comprehension, strip

I am using the Scrapy lib. I frequently get lists with '\t' and '\n'.

I'm trying to use list comprehensions to strip and remove resulting empty elements, but end up with the empty elements still.

Could someone explain how the interpreter is processing the code? It's seems that it is checking for empty elements, THEN stripping and re-inserting elements into the list.

Thank you in advance!

```
# input
char_list = ['', '    a','b', '\t']
print char_list
char_list = [x.strip() for x in char_list if x!='']
print char_list

# output
['', '    a', 'b', '\t']
['a', 'b', '']

#DESIRED output
['', '    a', 'b', '\t']
['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually in this situation, I'll change it into 2 steps... In the first step, I do the potentially expensive processing.  In the second step, I do the filtering.  The first step can be done with a generator expression to avoid unnecessary lists:

```
char_list_stripped = (x.strip() for x in char_list)
char_list = [x for x in char_list_stripped if x]
```

In this case, it saves you from calling `x.strip` twice as many times as you actually need to (if you were to pack it all into a single comprehension).  That's probably not *huge* savings (you'll likely not notice the speed difference).  But in the more general case, it could make a significant difference depending on how much work the processing actually entails.

Answer (score 4):

```
char_list = [x.strip() for x in char_list if x.strip()]
```

what you want is remove the useless strings. x!="" cant remove the "\t".

Comment: Thanks for the response. Why are you performing the strip() function twice?

Comment: Just want to give what you want

Comment: First strip gives the required strip, second one checks the condition, so first one will only run second strip is true.

Comment: @jsmiao The real question is why are you performing the `strip` function once, the reason why your code doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

A double comprehension will be more efficient than a single comprehension with two calls to strip()

```
char_list = [ x for x in [ x.strip() for x in char_list ] if x ]
```

Comment: mgilsons generator is even more efficient but can still be single step
    `char_list = [ x for x in ( x.strip() for x in char_list ) if x ]`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> char_list = ['', '    a','b', '\t']
>>> filter(None, map(str.strip, char_list))
['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good practice to hardcode such things in spiders. Look at Scrapy's [built-in Item Loader](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) and input/output processors.
Try the following in your REPL:

```
from  scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import MapCompose

def compact(s):
    """ returns None if string is empty, otherwise string itself """
    return s if s else None

char_list = ['', '    a','b', '\t']
MapCompose(unicode.strip, compact)(char_list)
=> ['a', 'b']
```

[MapCompose](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.contrib.loader.processor.MapCompose) applies given functions on each item in sequence, each function takes one item as argument, excluding None from future processing.

The easiest way to use this approach in your items.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from  scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import MapCompose

def compact(s):
    return s if s else None

class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    my_field = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(unicode.strip, compact)
    )
```

And in your spider's parse_my_items callback:

```
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from myproject.items import MyItem

il = ItemLoader(item=MyItem())
il.add_value('my_field', char_list)
my_item = il.load_item()
yield my_item
#=> {'my_field': [u'a', u'b']}
```

Hope this helps!